# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError is chasing me at Cloudbees

Tags: java, playframework, cloudbees, ebean, playframework-2.2

My Play 2.2.1 app works perfectly on my home machine.

After been pushed to Cloudbees it was compiled and deployed successfully.

But in runtime when I'm accessing the URL of the app I sometimes get 502 Bad Gateway. Then I can do **bees app:restart** and problem could disappear or could not. Then I do **bees app:restart** and it could appear again.

I can see absolutely no logic behind it. After 50% of restarts it appears.

Here is the stacktrace from logs:

```
Play server process ID is 782
[[37minfo[0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/totointer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.avaje.ebean.config.AutofetchConfig.isGarbageCollectionOnShutdown()Z
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.autofetch.DefaultAutoFetchManager.setOwner(DefaultAutoFetchManager.java:98)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.autofetch.AutoFetchManagerFactory.createAutoFetchManager(AutoFetchManagerFactory.java:29)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.autofetch.AutoFetchManagerFactory.create(AutoFetchManagerFactory.java:23)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.createAutoFetchManager(InternalConfiguration.java:154)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.<init>(DefaultServer.java:237)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:207)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:65)
    at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:59)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:79)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like conflicting version of same jar in classpath, one of them has AutofetchConfig class but no isGarbageCollectionOnShutdown method.  I notice for sample on [API doc](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/config/AutofetchConfig.html) that this method doesn't exist in 2.6.0, but exists in [3.2.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje.ebeanorm/avaje-ebeanorm/3.2.2/com/avaje/ebean/config/AutofetchConfig.java#AutofetchConfig.isGarbageCollectionOnShutdown%28%29)